# How to save image in PHP while using rithychhen image editor

Tags: php, ajax, image, html5-canvas

I have been trying to incorporate the image editing feature onto my site and have used the following plugin:

http://rithychhen.com/jquery/imageEditor

All the features provided in this plugin works fine. But I am hung up while saving the image to the server.

As directed in the above provided website, I have specified the "**remote URL**" and set the "**remoteSave**" to true. But I have no clue on how to work on the PHP side(as I have no clue of the header variable set by the image editor which is sent in Ajax call).

Comment: The relevant code snippets might help.

Comment: @wwkudu Can you help me with some relevant links!!!

Comment: @sanketh you can of course open the console of the browser and inspect the header of the ajax call. it will be for sure a dataurl. can you check it?

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi Thanx ..I have solved the problem :)